# How to catch exceptions of copytree in python

Tags: python

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) of `shutil.copytree` states:

> If exception(s) occur, an [Error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.Error) is raised with a list of reasons.

And the link refers to:

> exception shutil.Error
> This exception collects exceptions that are raised during a multi-file operation. For copytree(), the exception argument is a list of 3-tuples (srcname, dstname, exception).

What is this `shutil.Error` exception? I tried to catch this type of exception:

```
try:
  shutil.copytree(source, dest) # this throws a FileExistsError for example
except shutil.Error:
    # error handling
```

But this kind of error wasn't raised..

Comment: is you know `FileExistsError` is raised, why not using it ? then `Exception` after in case something else happen

Comment: This is only one exception I know that may be raised. There may be others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation first states

> `dirs_exist_ok` dictates whether to raise an exception in case dst or any missing parent directory already exists.

Unless you specify `dirs_exist_ok=True` a `FileExistsError` is raised. You're right that later on the documentation states that (presumably in other cases) a `shutil.Error` may be raised.

In the end I think it's a matter of interpretation, but if the code raises a `FileExistsError` you should catch a `FileExistsError`:

```py
try:
  shutil.copytree(source, dest)
except FileExistsError:
    # error handling
```

```
>>> shutil.copytree("ws", "workshop")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/robin/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 554, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
  File "/home/robin/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 455, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
  File "/home/robin/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'workshop'
>>> shutil.copytree("ws", "workshop", dirs_exist_ok=True)
'workshop'
```

The part of `shutil.Error` that you quoted could be interpreted as:

> This exception collects exceptions that are raised during a multi-file operation. For copytree(), [*when a `shutil.Error` is raised*] the exception argument is a list of 3-tuples (srcname, dstname, exception).

It does not mean that all exceptions during `copytree()` will be of type `shutil.Error`.

Comment: One could argue that `Error` will be raised if something happens *during* the copying process; `FileExistsError` is raised before that process even begins. The documentation could certainly be clearer, though.